# High energy collision of two proton

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, scattering, protons

Suppose there are two protons ( as we have in LHC). One proton is coming from +ve z axis and other from -ve z axis toward the collision point(origin). Both proton collide with equal velocity. Now as collision happen at very high velocity. So lot of particles will be produced due to various scattering processes.

My question is in which direction scattered particle density will be high. That is

in xy plane ( perpendicular to the direction of proton motion)

or
along the direction of motion of proton that is in z or -z direction.

In other words. I am asking in which direction particles will be get boosted.
I will be thankful by your answers.

Comment: You are in the center of momentum frame.

Comment: have a look at events in ATLAS https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/AtlasPublic/EventDisplayRun2Collisions to see how proton proton collisions displayu